# How to take string input using NUNIT with c#

Tags: c#, nunit

I am new in Nunit framework. So Please some one tell how to take input string through keyboard using NUNIT with c#.

Comment: NUnit is a unit testing framework for automated testing. If you're doing keyboard input, you're not unit testing. I think you're trying to use NUnit for the wrong thing :)

Comment: Maybe you want to populate some textboxes on your forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.  Unit tests are intended to be run automatically, without user input.  If you need user input for your tests, then you need to rethink how you are designing your tests and re-work them to only work with pre-stored data, like hardcoded strings or resource files.